# How to work out a % increase in value up to or above a range of numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Got a task to work out the value of some shares but only if the value is up to or between a certain amount.

[image: Example]

The value in C2 can be between 0-25.

For Class B, I need a formula that represents 5% of the value in C2 but only up to 10.

For Class D, the formula needs to show the value of 2.5% but only when the value in C2 is between 10-25

Have no idea where to start, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: When would 5% of a value between 0 and 25 be over 10?

Comment: Start by looking up the `IF` function in Excel's Help. You can start Help by pressing F1 (the button on the right-hand side of the top left one). BTW, is this your homework?

Answer (score 0):

We try not to answer people's homework for them, but here are some hints for you to get you started:

Functions begin with `=`.  That's what tells Excel to do a calculation.

Reference cells directly, so you could do something like `=c2*0.05` in any cell to find 5% of the value in `c2`.

Use `if` to make things happen sometimes.  So, if you want to only do something if `c2` is over 10, use `=if(c2>10, over_ten_answer, below_ten_answer)`  (`over_ten_answer` and `below_ten_answer` are just placeholders for bits of formula that you could use in those spots.)

Hopefully, that should be enough to get your going.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into learning how to nest if statements if you're going to do a lot if this type of data manipulations. See below for a simple nested if formula to resolve

=IF(A1<26,IF(A1<11,A1*0.05,A1*0.025),0)

I have the value that you want the 2.5% or 5% of in cell A1 in the above. If the number is above 25, The formula that I have here will set it to 0(just replace the 0 at the end with whatever you want it to return).